# How to export a module

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I started learning from https://egghead.io/technologies/es6 the ECMAScript 6 way, knowing there is still a lot that might change, but wanted to get a early start.

However, when I follow the tutorial instructions on (https://egghead.io/lessons/ecmascript-6-es6-modules-es2015-import-and-export) exactly the same, I get an error which I have no idea what I might have done wrong.

**Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined**

Code on that line after Babel converted to ES5

```
"use strict";

var _distExporter = require("dist/exporter");

console.log("2 + 3=", (0, _distExporter.sumTwo)(2, 3));
//# sourceMappingURL=importer.js.map
```

Developers are mentioning CommonJS and WebPack as a solution some even mentioned RequireJS, but nowhere in the tutorial did it state I should should code or use alternative libraries.

**My HTML is this**

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="dist/importer.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

**My importer.js is**

```
import { sumTwo } from "dist/exporter";

console.log( "2 + 3=", sumTwo(2,3))
```

**And my exporter.js is**

```
function sumTwo(a, b){
  return a + b;
}

export { sumTwo };
```

I have no idea where I'm going wrong. I'm using BabelJS (https://babeljs.io/)

Comment: "Developers are mentioning CommonJS and WebPack as a solution some even mentioned RequireJS, but nowhere in the tutorial did it state I should should code or use alternative libraries." — It looks like the guide you linked to does mention WebPack: https://www.evernote.com/l/AAPz2VWLUdRKjaPTzyxh1bo7UjUEvaDO1YY

Comment: Browsers don't have `require` defined, so if you want to use your modules in a browser environment, you do have to use WebPack, Browserify (http://browserify.org/) or similar to bundle your modules.

Comment: Awesome thanks guys I think my light inside my brain has sorta come one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run this code under Node, rather than in a browser, you should see the results you are expecting. Node understands CommonJS require calls and will go away and grab that other file for you.

The browser has no idea that require is anything special. But we can use a tool to make the browser understand. Here's an example with [Browserify](http://browserify.org/), as some other people have mentioned you can also use [WebPack](http://webpack.github.io/), but I think the learning curve for WebPack is a lot steeper.

First you'll need a couple of modules.

```
npm install -g browserify
npm install --save-dev babelify
```

Then we can use these modules together like this.

```
browserify main-file.js -o output-file.js -t babelify
```

This will walk your source files checking calls to require in each one and adding the other files that it requires to the bundle. Then it runs the Babel transform over it, to convert ES6 to ES5. Finally it wraps it all up in some code that lets require work in a browser.

Comment: Hi Dan so I have browserify installed and babel off course but im receiving this error in console : Cannot find module  "exporter" from C:\Lessons\ES6\dist

Comment: Ok I managed to fix it using browserify: {'main/bundle.js': '/dist/importer.js']      }, However I see my bundle.js file doesnt really contain any of my code very.

Comment: You'll have better luck if you use Browserify with a Babel transform (babelify), rather than trying to use babel as a separate task. In fact if you want to watch files to, I'd suggest looking at [watchify](https://github.com/substack/watchify). You can run `watchify main/bundle.js -o dist/importer.js -t babelify` without needing to use Grunt at all.

Comment: Thanks Dan, let me give it a go. Appreciate the help!